# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type

Tags: eclipse, spring

I am frequently getting the below error while running the application in eclipse. does anyone come across this problem or know how to fix it?

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.employee.service.customfield.impl.EmployeeMapper] is defined: expected single bean but found 0:

The same application works fine in command promot via mvn (maven)

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Show us your Application Context configuration files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this error means is that your configuration is different between Eclipse and your command line (probably caused by a difference in the classpath).  If you're running this from Eclipse using a run configuration, you probably need to make some tweaks to the classpath settings either in the run config, or on the project's build path.

As an example, if you've got a `spring-mybatis.xml` application context file under `src/main/resources` that defines your `EmployeeMapper` bean, but Eclipse isn't configured to pick this up as part of the build path, this would cause an error like this (maven will pick up this directory by default)

Answer (score 0):

This error occures after I altered the JRE version in Debug Configuration. To handle this get to the classpath tab in the debug configuration. Edit the configuration in user entries. Check the *Only include exported entries* checkbox.